# In boost::multi_index, will modifying a field, which is a key in another index, cause that index to reshuffle?

Tags: c++, boost-multi-index

The situation is as follows:
I'm having a bmi, indexed by `hashed_unique` over a `name` field of the struct and `ordered_non_unique`, over the `status` field of the same struct. The question is: if I invoke modify() on the `hashed_unique` index and modify a `status` field with it, will this cause a rebalance on the `ordered_non_unique` index? Or should I explicitly use modify() on the `ordered_non_unique` index while altering `status` in order to keep it updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modify` will cause all indices to reorder as necessary regardless of which index it is called on.